# Redirect and scroll to specific content

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, yii, jquery-scrollable

hi guys can any one have idea  whenever i click from footer link a new page will be open and the will scroll to a specific content below is the screen shot. Condition is the website is in yii framework and nothing others.

[image: Footer Links on any page]

[image: the content page where scroll to the specific area content]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an anchor in your HTML with `<a id="some-content"></a>` and change the location to `some/action#some-content`.

Answer (score 2):

using <a> you can create that functionality

```
<a id="travel">Travel Privileges</a>
```

and try to add `#travel` in the location bar
Ex:

```
http://somedomain/privileges#travel
```